# Stream from webRTC to wowza streaming engine

Tags: webrtc, wowza

I want to send stream from my camera to wowza streaming enging. I used webRTc for this. I installed webRTc.zip and follow all steps in readme.html . I am able to open publish page and see stream from my camera to screen. But this stream never reached to my application in wowza streaming engine. And i am getting this error in console in javascript .

Please help in this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzGZJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a [parsing error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/JSON_bad_parse).  Likely the response was an error and not actually JSON.  You will discover your issue by outputting what you are trying to parse (i.e. `console.log(http.responseText)

You can also see why that response might have been an error on the server-side logs under `/usr/local/WowzaStreamingEngine/logs`

Answer (score 0):

In sdp URL change the https to wss

like **wss://xxxxxxxxasdasxx.streamlock.net/webrtc-session.json**

Then try to publish.